# String format in c# text

Tags: c#

Strings in C# casts off right zeros. I want it don't cast off this zeros. For example:

> 1->00001
>
> 11->00011

Also, I want 5 fixed decimals as in the example. I didn't do that with String.Format method. Do I miss something? How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`someString.PadLeft(int, char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine ("11".PadLeft(5, '0'));
```

> Use one of the following String methods to create a new string that consists of an original string that is padded with leading or trailing characters to a specified total length. The padding character can be spaces or a specified character, and consequently appears to be either right-aligned or left-aligned.

Comment: I must give you mad props for your last comment on that deleted question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.ToString(string)` overload, like:

```
int number = 1
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("D5")); // 00001

int number = 11
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("D5")); // 00011
```

Or explicitly:

```
int number = 1
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("00000")); // 00001
```